# placeholde'ы в тестах при чтении xml-файлов при помощи jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

У меня есть файл user.xml

Его содержимое:

```
<User>
  <name>Tania</name>
  <surname>Ivanova</surname>
</User>
```

Файл использую в тестах и читаю так:

```
private Object readFromFile(String fileName) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    File file = new File(getClass().getResource(fileName).getFile());

    return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
}
```

Можно ли, и как, сделать так, чтобы не делать множество xml- файлов на все возможные в имена в тестах, User1.xml, User2.xml, а использовать один файл как шаблон и передавать значения, которые будут подставляться в соответствующие места в файле и, получается, смогу получить изменяемый xml-файл.

Answer (score 0):

Если сущность User содержит немного полей(но даже и если и много) и используется в тесте я бы предложил не читать объект их файла, а создавать его. В таком подходе будут следующие плюсы:

- монипулирование java объектами проще чем xml
- поможет избежать проблем с *долгим* выполнением ваших тестов.